# How to Flask_login.login_required decorator Client side

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am trying to implement a **Python server** implementing the **Flask** framework and also the extension **Flask Login**.
Flask Login supports a decorator **@login_required** to ensure a user is logged in before accessing the function.

My next step is to write an Android client side. 
I realized that the successful login at the serverside includes a **cookie**.

How do i pass the **@login_required** with my next request?
For example to have access to the /show_all part?

This is how the login function itself:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    sys.stdout.write("/login \n")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        given_username = request.form['username']
        given_password = request.form['password']
        if given_username is None or given_password is None:
            abort(401)
        user = valid_login(given_username, given_password)
        if user is not None:
            user.authenticated = True
            login_user(user)
            return "Success"
        else:
            abort(401)
```

For completeness the complete code:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://xxxx'
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

engine = db.create_engine('mysql://xxxx')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

def valid_login(given_username, given_password):
    result = User.query.filter_by(username=given_username, password=given_password)
    if result.count() > 1:
        sys.stdout.write("too many users found by login")
    elif result.count() == 1:
        return result.first()
    return None

def check_permission(doc_id, user_id):
    right = Right.query.filter_by(docid = doc_id, userid = user_id).first()
    if right is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        given_username = request.form['username']
        given_password = request.form['password']
        if given_username is None or given_password is None:
            abort(401)
        user = valid_login(given_username, given_password)
        if user is not None:
            user.authenticated = True
            login_user(user)
            return "Success"    
        else:
            abort(401)

@app.route('/showall', methods=['GET'])
@flask_login.login_required
def show_all():
    try:
        result = Right.query.filter_by(userid = current_user.userid).all()
        body = {}
        for r in result:
            print(str(r) + ' \n', file=sys.stdout)
            doc = Doc.query.filter_by(docid = r.docid).first()
            body[doc.docid] = [doc.docname, doc.directory, doc.company, doc.timestamp]

        response = app.response_class( response=json.dumps(body,indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str), mimetype='application/json')
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        abort(400)

@app.route('/showone/<int:doc_id>', methods=['GET'])
@flask_login.login_required
def show_one(doc_id):
    if check_permission(doc_id, current_user.userid):
        print('permission ok \n', file=sys.stdout)
        body = {}
        doc = Doc.query.get_or_404(doc_id)
        return app.response_class(doc.document, mimetype='application/octet-stream')    
    else:
        print('permission not ok \n', file=sys.stdout)
        abort(401)

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
@flask_login.login_required
def logout():
    current_user.authenticated = False
    db.session.commit()
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)


#SQLAlchemy classes for queries to the database

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'userinfo'

    userid = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    company = db.Column(Integer)
    username = db.Column(db.String)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return self.userid

    def is_authenticated(self):
        if self.authenticated is True:
            print('authenticated \n', file=sys.stdout)
        else:
            print('NOT AUTHENTICATED\n', file=sys.stdout)
        return self.authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

class Right(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'rights'
    userid = db.Column(Integer)
    docid = db.Column(Integer)
    rightid = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Doc(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'documents'
    docid = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    docname = db.Column(db.String)
    directory = db.Column(db.String)
    document = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    company = db.Column(Integer)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    companyname = db.Column(db.String)
    companyid = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.warning("App run")
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put the decorator in the right position but the correct syntax for the decorator is `@login_required`. In your case, once the login has been validated, redirect to the login required page:

```
...
login_user(user)
return redirect(url_for('user.dashboard'))

@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return '200'
```

Refer to the docs [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see a couple of examples.

It may also be easier to validate the form through [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) with their validate_on_submit() function.

Comment: So if I write a new request at the client side, what do i need to do? Do I need to add the cookie or does the server normally remember me himself?

Comment: For flask login, you add the remember me parameter:  ‘login_user(user, remember=true)’ - this will create a cookie stored on the users computer. You can also use ‘duration(datetime.timedelta)’ parameter to determine how long the user’s sessions is ‘remembered’.

Comment: How did you go @JasminDe? Did this end up working for you?